# Flask auto-reloader not working, though debug-mode is on?

Tags: python, flask, debugging

As can be seen I am loading the config file .env and in addition I'm running with debug=True

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# Load environment variables from .env file
load_dotenv()

# Create Flask app instance
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**.env:**

```
FLASK_DEBUG=1 
FLASK_APP=app
```

**terminal:**

```
flask run

 * Serving Flask app 'app'
 *** Debug mode: on**
WARNING: ....
WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 140-343-514
```

How can I resolve this? I've tried the Livereloader plugin and it doesn't work. I've tried a different browser. Nothing works. Please can you help?

Thank you

Comment: Use `app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True`

Comment: Unforuntately, adding this to app.py still not enable auto reload